# How to `List + List = List[List]]`

Tags: haskell

How can I add a List to another, returning a List of Lists?

```
foo :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example, my desired result of:

```
foo [1,2] [3,4]
```

would be `[[1,2], [3,4]]`.

`++` didn't work:

```
*Main> [1,2] ++ [3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely just this would work?

```
foo :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
foo a b = [a, b]
```

Comment: Also note that `[a, b]` is sugar for `a : b : []`; so if you ever need something more general you can use `(:[])` to create a singleton list and `(:)` to prepend further elements. If you want to confuse people you can even write `foo` pointfree as `foo = (.(:[])).(:)`

Comment: Could you please give an example of `(:[])`? `Prelude> (:[]) : 3` isn't working` in REPL.

Comment: `(:[])` is a function, since `(:)` is an infix function `a -> [a] -> [a]` and its right argument is `[]` we get a new function `(:[])` with type `a -> [a]`.  You can apply this to anything to put it in a singleton list, e.g. `(:[]) 5 = [5]`

Answer (score 7):

It is a bit funny that you almost wrote the answer to your question yourself:

> foo [1,2] [3,4]
>   would be [[1,2], [3,4]].

Now, all you need to do mentally is to abstract from concrete example values! Replace `[1,2]` with `a` and `[3,4]` with `b` for example. Then you can tell Haskell that you want

> foo a b = [a, b]

And that is it! Although it has a more general type than what you intended.

Comment: I like the way you explained it through abstraction, very helpful. +1